# const decimal giving warning - value is never used

Tags: c#

I was doing some code, and found this :

```
class Prac
{
    const int valInt = 7;
    const decimal valDec = 7;
}
```

> Prac.cs(4,19): warning CS0414: The field ‘Test.valDec’ is assigned but its value is never used.

But there is no warning for `int`.

Why this difference between behaviour of `int` and `decimal`.

Comment: Are you sure valInt in not being used?

Comment: @JonSkeet wrote article about it: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/22/when-is-a-constant-not-a-constant-when-its-a-decimal/